# Autoconf: Putting more stuff in config.h or generating confdefs.h

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I want to add Autoconf/Automake to an existing project.  One of the things I need to do is pass compile-time defines like `PREFIX` to the program.  I seem to recall that quite some time ago this stuff appeared in `config.h`, but no longer.  At the very end of `config.log`, I see what looks like the contents of `configdefs.h` which has exactly what I want.

How can I get the configure script to create the file `configdefs.h` for me or put it in `config.h`?

Here's what I have:

autogen.sh:

```
autoheader && aclocal && automake -a -c -f && autoconf
```

Makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS =
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT(foo, 1.0, joe@foo.com)    
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([foo.c])

# Using the former instead of the latter AC_CONFIG_HEADERS results in
# automake complaining about lack of confdefs.h.in.
# autoheader doesn't help
#AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h] [confdefs.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_PROG_CC
if test x$prefix = xNONE ; then
  prefix=${ac_default_prefix}
fi

# I want this stuff to go into config.h or confdefs.h
AC_DEFINE([STUFF], ["blahblah"], [Stuff])
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(DOCDIR, ["${prefix}/share/doc/foo"], [Documentation])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: You having used `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])`, `config.h` is where all the definitions are going to go (at least through Autoconf v2.69).  I don't, however, see anything in your configure.ac that would justify an expectation for a `PREFIX` symbol to be included there. `confdefs.h` is normally generated and used *internally* for autoconf tests; it is not the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Moreover, although I had to tweak your `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` call to add a description argument before autoheader would accept it, after I did so, the generated configure script indeed did output `STUFF` and `DOCDIR` defines in `config.h`.  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I was fighting with this problem for several hours last night.  I think I got tired and missed the fact that I finally got what I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Most common reason for customizing the config.h filename is porting an existing library and its accompanying include files.



Is this the case?

Otherwise, I recommend staying with config.h for each unique autoconf package.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for wanting to use something other than `config.h` is when porting a library (and its accompanying include files) into your project.

In real world, I ported Mozilla JS engine into my project and opted to create a new `config.h` as not to tamper with the Mozilla codebase (which has its own `config.h`).

I added the following to my project's `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([js-moz-config.h])
```

Then added it to the ported library in `Makefile.am`:

```
libmozjs_la_HEADERS = ... js-moz-config.h
```

Then created my project-specific include file for using Mozilla JS engine called `js-config.h`.

So that is looks like this:

```
libmozjs
 +- jstypes.h (Mozilla)
   +- js-config.h  (my object type customization)
     +- js-mozjs-config.h (Mozilla)
```